# Flutter package vibrate 0.0.4 is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart-pub, vibration

Trying to add vibration on button click in flutter, it works fine for Android. But in iOS it fails to compile with below error

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'vibrate/VibratePlugin.h' file not found
```

I am following the exact steps as stated here.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/vibrate#-installing-tab-

Here is the Xcode Build output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on ###'s iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: #####
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           13.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
    The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
    /Users/####/Flutter_Projects/project_####l/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'vibrate/VibratePlugin.h' file not found
    #import <vibrate/VibratePlugin.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
```

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same issue when building my flutter app for iOS and found this link that solved it for me.

https://github.com/benjamindean/flutter_vibration/issues/1

The answer I believe is to edit your .../appname/ios/Podfile

Go to the section that says:

```
target 'Runner' do
  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
```

and add the "use_frameworks!" right under the "target 'Runner' do" like this:

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
```

Comment: The question was related to another plugin - flutter_vibrate. That solution doesn't help unfortunately. It gives an error: 
```- `flutter_vibrate` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`Runner`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod.```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below line in pod file under project>iOS>podfile under target 'Runner' do[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTxN4.png)
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static